# Asymmetric hyperbola-type curve? (for fitting to data)

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

I have this question: what would be the name and equation of a curve which resembles a parabola but has not the requirement of symmetry?

So the general parabola equation is:

$y=ax^2+bx+c$

I must fit such a curve to data that resembles that shape. @Travis below suggested the equation of:

$y = x+\frac{1}{x}$

and this is the kind of function I'm looking for, save for the fact taht I need to fit a single "branch" to data.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Its symmetry is one of the essential features of a parabola. Can you be more specific about the type of behavior you want in the curve? Is it more like the graph of $y = x + \frac{1}{x}, x > 0$ or the graph of $y = x^3$?

Comment: Hi Travis, I just plotted it and actually $x+\frac{1}{x}$ looks similar to what I'm looking for. Something along these lines but with a single "branch" Thanks!

Comment: I updated the question...

Comment: Of course, one can simply define a curve to be the graph of the function $x \mapsto x + \frac{1}{x}$, $x > 0$.

Comment: Thanks Travis, in order to fit it to data, should I add parameters like: $ax+b(\frac{1}{x})$?

Comment: I suppose so, but I can't imagine what kind of data would naturally obey such a distribution.

Comment: The data follows somehow such a shape, but if you can think of other model, that'd be great too. thanks!

Comment: There are lots of functions with similar qualitative features. Perhaps you could describe the nature of your data in your question, so that people could offer better-educated suggestions?

Comment: It's similar to projectiles with air resistance, but more variable.

Comment: Could you post data points ?